# Cannot set text color of Send and Cancel buttons in the mail composer when presented from the UIActivityViewController in iOS7

Tags: ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using the UIActivityViewController to share items in iOS7. When I tap on the Mail option, it pops up the mail composer, but the Cancel and Send buttons on the navigation bar and the navigation bar itself are blue, making it very difficult to read, so I want to change their color. It's working in iOS6 but not in iOS7.

I tried

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

which works in iOS6, and I tried

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

which causes the color to flash red the first time the app is run before immediately switching  back to the blue color.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Hopefully someone knows what's up.

Comment: Also having the same issue here... Have you found a solution / workaround yet?

Comment: I don't know if you still watch this, but I gave an answer that is the solution to your problem. iOS 7 button colours are set using the navigation bar tint color.

Answer (score 76):

Managed to change the text color of the **Send** and **Cancel** buttons, which are on the `UINavigationBar` in the `MFMailComposerViewController` (both **Send** and **Cancel**) and `MFMessageComposeViewController` (only **Cancel**), when presented from `UIActivityViewController`.

Using an UIActivityViewController, tap on `Message`or `Mail`:

[image: Using an UIActivityViewController]

You'll notice that the default text color of the **Send** and **Cancel** buttons is blue:

[image: Default blue colors]

In order to change that, in the `AppDelegate.m` class, in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, insert the following line:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

This results in:

[image: Changed to white]

You can also use other colors, for example:

`[UIColor purpleColor];`

[image: Change to purple]

`[UIColor greenColor];`

[image: Changed to green]

**How did I test this? I noticed this solution works for the following:**

- with Xcode 5.1, in the iOS 7.1 simulator, building as base iOS SDK 7.1 (can be chosen from selecting the project file -> Build Settings -> Base SDK. Also, selected from General -> Deployment Target -> 7.1)
- with Xcode 5.1, on an iPhone 4, building as base iOS SDK 7.0 (can be chosen from selecting the project file -> Build Settings -> Base SDK. Also, selected from General -> Deployment Target -> 7.0)
- with Xcode 5.1, on an iPhone 4, building as base iOS SDK 7.1 (can be chosen from selecting the project file -> Build Settings -> Base SDK. Also, selected from General -> Deployment Target -> 7.1)

**It didn't work when testing with:**

- with Xcode 5.1, in the iOS 7.0 simulator, building as base iOS SDK 7.0 (can be chosen from selecting the project file -> Build Settings -> Base SDK. Also, selected from General -> Deployment Target -> 7.0)

Therefore it should be safe to use, as I believe the behavior on the actual device matters more than the behavior in the iOS simulator. 
If anyone knows why it doesn't work in the iOS 7.0 simulator, I would like to know. :)

Comment: I tried it with Xcode 5.1 iOS 7.1 simulator and iPhone 5s iOS 7.1 and it did not work

Comment: Works on device with iOS 7.1 but not on device with iOS 7.0. Got it working with @paillou's answer below

Comment: For swift apps the equivalent of this is `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` in AppDelegate (`UINavigationBarButtonItem` I think is necessary to directly replicate this).

Comment: Still changes status bar color :(

Comment: it's not working, can you suggest some code, i'm using tabbar controllers also

Comment: This seems to work for me on iOS 11 in Swift 4: `UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.white`

Answer (score 25):

Bar tint color and status bar color in UIActivityViewController.
Swift 3 solution:

```
extension MFMailComposeViewController {
    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationBar.isOpaque = false
        navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirmed it works on iOS10, both as it is and adapted to Swift 2.3.

Comment: You can freely remove UIStatusBarStyle and UIColor, leaving only .lightContent and .white

Comment: Best and more elegant solution. Works with buttons but I can't make it work with barTint in iOS10 for any reason

Comment: To change the color of the title add let whiteColor = UIColor.white let attributedStringColour : NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : whiteColor] navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =  attributedStringColour as? [String : AnyObject]

Comment: I don't think we should be overriding methods in extensions.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what works on iOS 7.1 as of today.

Subclass the UIActivityViewController and override the following method:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    viewControllerToPresent.view.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

        if (completion) {
            completion();
        }
    }];
}
```

This will make the buttons white and the status bar white.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me from everything suggested on the WHOLE INTERNET - Thank you @Macijej!

Answer (score 4):

For **Swift:**

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: { () in
   UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
   UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // optional to change bar backgroundColor           
}
```

This will change *Send* & *Cancel* button color to White (tested on iOS 7,8) but am still not able to make status bar text color white.( Although I have not tried that Subclass  `UIActivityViewController` solution to change statusbar text color )

Comment: Ok I have not tested on latest versions done this long time ago, if anyone has solution for latest iOS version can suggest edit. Will update my answer

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my issue by extending the `UIActivityViewController` and overriding the `viewWillAppear` and `viewWilldisapper` methods:

```
extension UIActivityViewController {

    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    }
        
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: (247/255), green: (247/255), blue: (247/255), alpha: 1)
        //navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    open override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = mycustomColor
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug with iOS 7. I've seen other reports of this online. It also doesn't appear to be fixed in iOS 7.1.

To be specific, no matter what you do, you cannot set tint colors on navigation bars for dialogs shown from the UIActivityViewController.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my app where the `tintColor` property of `UINavigationBar` is white everywhere thanks to the appearance proxy. The resulting effect is that `UIBarButtonItem` from the mail composer view controller navigationBar were not visible (white buttons on a white navigation bar).

I have this call in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

As it is impossible (for now ?) to access the `UINavigationBar` of the mail composer view controller in the `UIActivityViewController`, I did the following workaround which is inspired from Alex's answer:

```
UIColor *normalColor = [[UINavigationBar appearance] tintColor];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
            [activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
                // back to normal color
                [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:normalColor];
            }];
            [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{
                // change color temporary
                [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0f/255.0f green:51.0f/255.0f blue:72.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
            }];
```

PS: this code is intented for iOS 7, but you can use `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:]` in iOS 6 (cf Kevin van Mierlo's answer)

Answer (score 1):

Well there are reasons for why we cannot change the way that the UI in apple's code is the way it is. Mostly because it is apple's. They do not allow you to edit the way the UI in MFMailComposerViewController looks in any way. If there is a way, then I have no clue about it, but I have never seen any way to do it. MFMailComposeViewController doesn't support the appearance attribute as it was created in iOS 3.0, and appearance didn't become a thing until iOS 5.0

Here is a link to the MFMailComposeViewController apple documentation: [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the color of the cancel and send buttons in iOS 7 you should use this:

```
// Change the colours of the buttons in iOS 7
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

In iOS 6 it is indeed these and you should also leave this in your code:

```
// Change the colours of the buttons in iOS 6
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

// Change the color of the the navigation bar in iOS 6 and 7
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for may be it will help you

```
[[mailComposer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get Alex's solution to work, however I have managed to get a variation of Paillou's answer to work although I had to set both the barTintColor and the titleTextAttributes in my situation:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    // back to normal color
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:AAColorInputBorder];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                         [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:18], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                         [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                         nil]];
}];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{
// change color temporary
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                     [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:18], NSFontAttributeName,
                                                     AAColorInputBorder, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                     nil]];
```

Thanks Paillou!

Comment: I don't know why it's so complicated to get things work correctly but it's the only solution working for me. I wonder how libraries like ShareKit do this...

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:
in AppDelegate.m in the function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I've entered the following code:

```
//mail composer
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setBarTintColor:myBackgroundColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MFMailComposeViewController class], nil] setTintColor:myBarItemsColor];
```

It works just fine on iOS7 + iOS8, did not try on newer versions

Comment: Did not work for me on iOS 9.2, nav bar buttons remained the standard blue

Comment: @Michael When i wrote it iOS8 was the newest - edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

For ios7 i think that you should go through this code

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

If it is also not working then try Mail Compose View Controller apple documentation available on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Before presenting the mail composer insert this line like this:

```
[mailComposer.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Even though I set the status bar style in application did finish launching I also needed to set it again in the completion block like this:

```
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:^{[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];}];
```

Comment: The question is about UIActivityViewController not MFMailComposeViewController

Answer (score 0):

I had enormous trouble with this, especially when `MFMailComposeViewController`/`MFMessageViewController` are themselves displayed by `UIActivityViewController`.

I resorted to using method swizzling on `viewDidAppear`/`viewDidDisappear` to undo and then redo my app's customisation of colors and fonts, with some help from https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle:

**SwizzledComposeViewControllers.h**

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface MFMailComposeViewController (GMSwizzling)
@end

@interface MFMessageComposeViewController (GMSwizzling)
@end
```

**SwizzledComposeViewControllers.m**

```
#import "SwizzledComposeViewControllers.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "JRSwizzle.h"

@implementation MFMailComposeViewController (GMSwizzling)

+ (void)load {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(init) withMethod:@selector(gmswizzled_init) error:nil];
    [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(viewWillAppear:) withMethod:@selector(gmswizzled_viewWillAppear:) error:nil];
    [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(viewWillDisappear:) withMethod:@selector(gmswizzled_viewWillDisappear:) error:nil];
  });
}

- (instancetype)gmswizzled_init {
  [(AppDelegate*)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate uncustomiseAppearance];
  return [self gmswizzled_init];
}

- (void)gmswizzled_viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [(AppDelegate*)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate uncustomiseAppearance];
  [self gmswizzled_viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)gmswizzled_viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [(AppDelegate*)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate customiseAppearance];
  [self gmswizzled_viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

@end


@implementation MFMessageComposeViewController (GMSwizzling)

+ (void)load {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(init) withMethod:@selector(gmswizzled_init) error:nil];
    [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(viewWillAppear:) withMethod:@selector(gmswizzled_viewWillAppear:) error:nil];
    [self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(viewWillDisappear:) withMethod:@selector(gmswizzled_viewWillDisappear:) error:nil];
  });
}

- (instancetype)gmswizzled_init {
  [(AppDelegate*)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate uncustomiseAppearance];
  return [self gmswizzled_init];
}

- (void)gmswizzled_viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [(AppDelegate*)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate uncustomiseAppearance];
  [self gmswizzled_viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)gmswizzled_viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [(AppDelegate*)UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate customiseAppearance];
  [self gmswizzled_viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

@end
```

(I have to admit I can't recall why I uncustomised appearances both in `init` and `viewWillAppear`, but I'm fairly sure there was a reason ...).

Answer (score 0):

In Swift I made an extension for `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func presentActivityViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController) {
        self.presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true) { _ in
            UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Config.primaryColor
        }
    }
}
```

When I need to present an UIActivityViewController I call:

```
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: [])
    presentActivityViewController(activityViewController)
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift**, on **iOS9**, setting

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor() // eg
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```

before presenting the activity view controller did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different methods in iOS 9 and 10, but this is the only one that worked. Note that I have a background image behind the navigationBar as well:

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
NSDictionary *attribs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor};
UINavigationBar.appearance.titleTextAttributes = attribs;
UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
[UINavigationBar.appearance setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IOSNavigationBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
UIBarButtonItem.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `appearance` before presenting `UIActivityViewController`. Add resetting of appearance to `completionWithItemsHandler` of your `activity VC`:

```
setNavBarAppearance()

activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak self] _, _, _, _ in
    self?.resetNavBarAppearance()
}

present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The only problem, that if activity is like mail sending, it is full screen. Your appearance will not be applied to current visible views. A little hacks to solve it:

```
setNavBarAppearance()

activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { [weak self] _, _, _, _ in
    self?.resetNavBarAppearance()

    // Hacks(choose one of them):
    // 1)
    self?.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self?.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    // 2)
    let redrawTriggerVC = UIViewController()
    redrawTriggerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    self.present(redrawTriggerVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    redrawTriggerVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a mechanism I liked, so for what it's worth here's mine.  Part of the trouble is later versions of iOS add the capability for apps to add system-wide Share and Action Extensions.  These third-party items seem to be coded all sorts of ways.  Some inherit the app's nav bar style, some use their own, and some seem to assume a white nav bar (but actually inherits from the app).

This is tested on iOS 12.2.

I create an `UIActivityItemSource`, to which I have:

```
- (nullable id)activityViewController:(nonnull UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(nullable UIActivityType)activityType {
    if (activityType == UIActivityTypePrint || [activityType.lowercaseString containsString:@"extension"] || [activityType containsString:@"AssignToContact"]) {
        //What a hack, but the best I can do.  Seems some extensions inherit nav style from parent, others don't.
        //ActionExtension is bottom row; all those I tested need this.  The string comparison catches most non-OS extensions (the type is set by developer).
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor kNavigationBarBackgroundColor]]; //kNavigationBarBackgroundColor is my app's custom nav bar background color
    } else {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
    return self.pdfData; //In my case I'm sharing a PDF as NSData - modify as needed for your shared item
}
```

Then in my `UIActivityViewController`'s `completionWithItemsHandler` I include:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor kNavigationBarBackgroundColor]]; //Again, this is my app's custom nav bar background color
```

Unrelated to the specific issue, but if you don't currently have a `UIActivityItemSource` you need to do something like this:

```
NSArray *activities=@[self]; //And set self to be a UIActivityItemSource
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activities applicationActivities:nil];
```

I'm sure this isn't 100% reliable, but worked with all extensions I tried.