# UIActivityViewController chosing SMS : How to add/display a CANCEL button?

Tags: ios, swift, sms, uiactivityviewcontroller, cancel-button

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
let textToShare = "Swift is awesome!  Check out this website about it!"

if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.codingexplorer.com/") {
    let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Hi, I add sms sharing to my app, everything works fine except I'd like to be able to CANCEL an SMS after I started it. 
No cancel Button is displayed in the uinavigationbar for SMS while it is present for Mail, Twitter or Facebook.

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code that modifies the `UINavigationBar` or something related to it?

Comment: `[UINavigationBar appearance]` in your  code refer link :[same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076369/facebook-uiactivityviewcontroller-is-missing-the-cancel-and-post-buttons)

Comment: Hi, So I checked appearence of UINavigation bar but still the button is missing. When debbuging in view hierarchie, button doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I found where this bug came from I had this pod in my project : 
https://github.com/kingiol/KDInteractiveNavigationController