# Change status bar text color of modal view controllers opening from a UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

How can we change the colour of a modal view controller getting opened after selecting an activity (mail, message etc.) from the `UIActivityViewController`.

I have tried setting `Status bar style` to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` but it did not work. `View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to `NO`. My app has a number of `UIViewController`s where I need the colour of the text of the status bar to be white while in some, I need it to be black and I need the colour of the status bar text to be white when activities are opened from the `UIActivityViewController`. How can this be achieved?

I have tried something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24909088/4533932) in the following manner -

```
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}];
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, except your method,we can use the method 

`- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle`

where the activityVC present, and return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent.Hope to help you.