# Set Done Button Colour on SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am using the `SFSafariViewController` to access a website called from a `UITableViewController`. Because my app has a very light feel attached to it, I have added the following line of code in the `AppDelegate`:

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

When running the `SFSafariViewController`, I get the following:

[image]

Is there anyway I can change the colour of the `Done` button to Blue (as per default)?

I've tried the following when calling the `SFSafariViewController` but to no effect:

```
        [self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:^{
            safariVC.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];


        [self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:^{
            safariVC.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }];
```

Neither of those work.

I could of course leave the app as default and take out the white setting from the `AppDelegate`, but I want this approach within the app because Blue just stands out too much with custom themes.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change bar colours globally using `appearance` proxy:

try

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

else try

```
  [self presentViewController:safariVC animated:YES completion:^{

         [safariVC.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }];
```

else try

in AppDelegate.m in the function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I've entered the following code:

```
//SFSafariViewController
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[SFSafariViewController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[SFSafariViewController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

or add in your ViewDidLoad

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

**Swift**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

else try this

```
self.presentViewController(safariVC, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
safariVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
})
```

or do like

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

     UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedIn(SFSafariViewController.self, nil).barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
UINavigationBar.appearanceWhenContainedIn(SFSafariViewController.self, nil).tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

or finally try this

```
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: see this link may be helps with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368122/cannot-set-text-color-of-send-and-cancel-buttons-in-the-mail-composer-when-prese

Comment: Thanks @Anbu - that's very helpful. Unfortunately, I just couldn't get this working, no matter what I tried from your answer, the link and any other answers. It just wouldn't show up as Blue in the SFSafariViewController. Do you have any further thoughts?

Comment: thats is the way man , I submit my answer in all methods, else check in new/old Xcode version once

Comment: Do you have it working on a device/simulator? I have self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; in the AppDelegate and I think that's overriding everything. That's important for me because I want every back button (Navigation Controller) to be white, but I just can't get the blue to appear.

Comment: Cool, I got it man. I removed the self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; from the AppDelegate and it defaults back to Blue and in each ViewController, I am adding     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; to the viewDidLoad and it works. Thanks for your help on this man! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Try
setPreferredControlTintColor 
to set tint color of Done button

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add code as well as the comments in the code itself 
- in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question. This is especially important for an older question and the questions that already have answers.

Comment: It's quite simple really. `let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL)
 svc.preferredBarTintColor = .black
 svc.preferredControlTintColor = .yellow` The first one colours the bar the second the controls' colours.

Comment: It dose save my time, and it should be the correct answer!