# Wrong text color in buttons when sharing with WhatsApp via UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uiappearance

When I share an text to WhatsApp with the `UIActivityViewController` the second screen of the sharing, for my case, has the wrong button colors.
The first screen is OK. This issue has been discussed a lot of times and one great bucket of answers can be found here: [Cannot set text color of Send and Cancel buttons in the mail composer when presented from the UIActivityViewController in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368122/cannot-set-text-color-of-send-and-cancel-buttons-in-the-mail-composer-when-prese)

The answer fixes for me the button colors of:

- MFMailComposeViewController
- And the first screen when sharing to
  WhatsApp

But for some reason not the second one.

This did the fix for the first screen:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

But even setting the appearance of all UIBarButtonItems is not working:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Example code not working:

```
self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.white
let activityController = UIActivityViewController.init(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)

if let vc = delegate?.currentViewController() {
    sender.isEnabled = false
    
    vc.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: {
        sender.isEnabled = true
    })
    activityController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    activityController.view.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

---

### Screenshots:

- First screen: (OK)

[image: Whatsapp first screen (OK)]

- Second screen (not OK)

[image: Whatsapp second screen (NOT OK)]

- Share by e-mail (OK)

[image: Email (OK)]

Comment: The solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47064914/3641812 helped me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just try by changing the UIWindow's `tintColor` in your `Appdelegate` method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. It will then automatically pass as default to all its UIView descendants.

```
[self.window setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Hope this will help you.

It could also be an issue with the third party which would be (overriding) setting the tintColor again.

Comment: @SjoerdPerfors It could also be an issue with the third party which would be overriding this setting.